# What is the cause of this windows Event Error: CbsPackageServicingFailure2

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I'm having an issue figuring out what the cause of the error below is. This error is appearing in the windows logs every ten seconds. I'm worried about what could happen to the system with this error appearing. Could someone please assist me in figuring out what this error is and what I could do to fix this.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CbsPackageServicingFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0Problem signature:
P1: 10.0.17763.1150
P2: Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-en-gb-Package
P3: 10.0.17763.1
P4: amd64
P5: unknown
P6: 8024402c
P7: CBS Other
P8: Absent
P9: Absent
P10: FodHelper(LanguageFeaturesOnDemand)Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBDBD.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xmlThese files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Critical_10.0.17763.1150_5edea83153742b71b41e74f382dd57b7fb8937_00000000_0c03a6daAnalysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 29f6dec4-04bb-4006-bb24-b2b4de0919f0
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket:
```

Thank you

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  (2) dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  (3) SFC /SCANNOW   .  Allow to complete, restart, run all Windows updates, test.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cbspackageservicingfailure2/40134d06-acaf-46f7-85c4-86f990f9a6fa

Comment: Check if the following link can help you:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors  Fix Windows Update errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness tool.

Comment: Maybe `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` could provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by enabling the following group policy setting:

gpedit.msc

'Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair'

and checking:

'Never attempt to download payload from Windows Update'

and

'Download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Update instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)'

checkboxes.

[image: ...]

Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair group policy setting